# Why is the matrix in Dirac's bracket formula invertible?

Tags: differential-geometry, classical-mechanics, symplectic-geometry

I am reading the book "Introduction to mechanics and symmetry" by J.Marsden and T.Ratiu and am experenced a problem.

Let $(P,\Omega)$ be a symplectic manifold, a submanifold $S\subset P$ is called a symplectic submanifold when $\omega:=i^*\Omega$ is a symplectic form on $S, i:S\rightarrow P$ being the inclusion.  Assume that $\dim P=2n,\dim S=2k$. In a neighborhood of a point $z_0\in S$, choose coordinates $z^1,...,z^{2n}$ on $P$ such that $S$ is given by $$z^{2k+1}=0,...,z^{2n}=0,$$
and so $z^1,...,z^{2k}$ provide the local coordinates for $S$.

In the formulation of Dirac's bracket formula, it appears the inverse of the matrix defined by $$C^{ij}(z)=\{z^i,z^j\},\ i,j=2k+1,...,2n.$$

The author said that it is easy to see one can choose coordinates such that the matrix $C=\{C^{ij}\}$ is invertible. But I cannot see the reason.

Thank you if you can give a short proof or refer me to a good reference.

Chengbo

Comment: What is your definition of $\{\cdot,\cdot\}$? For the Poisson bracket this seems obvious in canonical coordinates.

Comment: Yes, $\{\cdot,\cdot\}$ is Poisson bracket.

Comment: Can you show me how to use canonical coordinate to prove it?

Comment: I barely know any symplectic geometry so I'm hesitant to give an answer that might be perceived as authoritative, but you should be able to choose your $(z^1,\ldots,z^{2n})$ to be canonical coordinates $(q_1, p_1, \ldots , q_n, p_n)$, in which case the only non-zero terms of the bracket are $\{q_i, p_j\} = -\{p_j, q_i\} = \delta_{ij}$. Thus the matrix $C^{ij}$ will be block diagonal with every $2 \times 2$ block in the form $$\left[\begin{matrix}0&1\\-1&0\end{matrix}\right].$$

Comment: Thanks. I know the so-called Darboux theorm on canonical coordinate that you essentially mentioned. But it is not what I desire for the problem I am experienced.

Comment: Chengbo: So is your point that $z^1,\dots,z^{2n}$ is an *arbitrary* coordinate system on $P$ in which $S$ appears as flattened out? We're nowhere adapting our local coordinates to the symplectic geometry?

Comment: But you quoted the authors as saying that *one can choose coordinates so that ..." (as opposed to needing to check it for arbitrary coordinates), so, yes, why not use the Darboux coordinates where it's obvious?!

Comment: Ted Shifrin: Yes, it seems not necessary that $z^i$ is canonical coordinates.